# What use cases is `chdir` is needed for

Tags: node.js

I'm reading about `chdir` command in `node.js`, for example, this snippet:

```
console.log("The current working directory is " + process.cwd());
try {
    process.chdir("/");
} catch (exception) {
    console.error("chdir error: " + exception.message);
}
console.log("The current working directory is now " + process.cwd());
```

However, I can't figure out why would I need that. I'd appreciate a few use case examples for a general understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really very useful.  You can safely ignore it until such time that you encounter a situation where you really need your Node process to work in a different directory.  For example if you use some misbehaving library which dumps a file in the current directory, you can change the current directory before using that library.

Comment: Or you need to launch a standalone executable that expects (or works more easily) if started in a specific path.

Comment: @TripeHound: If you mean launch a child process, the standard API for that has an option to set the cwd for each new process.  You wouldn't use chdir.

Comment: OK. The couple of times I've needed to launch a child process I've not needed to set the directory, so I wasn't aware there was an option to do so (although I'm not surprised there is one).